# Getting current row when reading each row in Roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, roo

I'm currently using roo to read a set of spreadsheets.  I'd like to be able to skip certain rows when I itterate over each one (to skip header rows, etc).  Is there any way to do this?  I figure I could just use an index in the loop, but I was wondering if there was a "roo" way to do it.

**Something like:**

```
spreadsheet.each(c1: "Column1", c2: "Column2") do |therow|
    next if therow.row(1)
end
```

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried using `parse` method? it will return only the rows matching to a certain regex

Answer (score 0):

To skip header row, you can start from 2nd row to last_row as shown below:

```
    header = spreadsheet.row(1)
    (2..spreadsheet.last_row).map do |i|
      row = Hash[[header, spreadsheet.row(i)].transpose]

      if your_condition
        //do something otherwise ignore the row
      end
    end
```

Hope it helps